# Rendering a QGraphicsScene using OpenGL in Qt

Tags: image, qt, opengl, render

I'm trying to save a QGraphicsScene with OpenGL as an image (png or jpeg), but I don't want the image to depend on the current view (zoom). That's why I'm not using grabFrameBuffer but I use render() instead :

```
QImage imgToSave(1024,768,QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
// fill the image
// and define rectbuffer(), the QRect() containing what I want to save
QPainter painter(&imgToSave);
m_scene = new QGraphicsScene;
// fill the Scene
m_scene->render(&painter,imgToSave.rect(),rectbuffer());
```

It does work. My question is: is it using OpenGL capabilities or not?
If not, how to do so?

n.b. : i am using a QGLWidget as a Viewport for my GraphicsView. And the display using OpenGL is working. My concerns are about the image saving.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess: no.  Because for the QGraphicsScene to render through OpenGL you need to specify a QGLWidget derived object as the viewport of the scene - you haven't, so it's almost certainly using the raster engine.  Secondly the QPainter uses whatever paint device you construct it with as a backend, you have specified a straight QImage which does not use OpenGL.

If you can't/won't use a `QGLWidget` through a `QGraphicsView`, then you *might* be able to render onto `QGLFramebufferObject`.  But this brings it's own complications, namely you will have to create a hidden context beforehand.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
It's weird, I edited my first post but it's gone.
I was saying that i am indeed using a QGLWidget as a viewport. And that OpenGL is working for the display of the GraphicsScene.

So my issue is more about the image saving.
How can I specify to use OpenGL with my QPainter and render ? Do I have to choose another type than QImage ?

Comment: I've given a suggestion in my answer for a different paint device than QImage.  But remember that you will have to perform the render, then pull the data back off the card and push it into another image container (probably a QImage) to save/manipulate it - so you might not see much performance gain for lower resolution images.

Comment: So you're suggesting a QGLFrameBufferObject instead of QImage even if i'm using a QGLWidget ?

Comment: In your example you are using the `render()` call directly on the `QGraphicsScene`, the viewport's `QLGWidget` isn't being used (AFAIK).

Comment: I know, but I do have a QGLWdiget as Viewport. So could you tell me how to specify to use it with render(), if it is possible. If not, what must I look at ?
Thank you for helping me !

Comment: Presumably `QGLWidget::grabFrameBuffer()`, I haven't tried it before but it's a good place to start.

Comment: The problem with grabFrameBuffer, as I said, is that it depends on the current view/zoom. And you cannot define any region of interest such as a QRect.

Comment: Yes you did, apologies.  I suppose using a `QGLFramebufferObject` as the `QPainter` paint device is the next option.  But is rendering 1024x768 image through the raster engine really that slow?  It probably isn't worth this effort.

Comment: It's not THAT slow but still, i'd like to try. I appreciate your help anyway.

If anyone knows for sure if `render()` uses OpenGL or not when called in a QGraphicsScene with a QGLWidget as Viewport, that would be nice.